# port forwarding on this setup: Prolink 5200 modem/router connected to Linksys BEFSR41 v4.2

Tags: router, mac, port-forwarding

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6 on a 2006 Macbook. We recently switched ISPs and our new ISP gave us a Prolink 5200 Hurricane modem/router. We have another computer in the house but the 5200 only has one port, so we connected it to a Linksys BEFSR41 v4.2 4-port (wired) router.

Now the connection is phone line -> Prolink -> Linksys -> 2 computers. My question is how do I forward ports on this setup? I know how to forward ports if only one of those routers (I use 
[portforward](http://portforward.com) as my reference) is connected but not if they're linked.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to forward the port on the external router to the same port on the internal routers ip address then on the internal router forward the port to the PC with the software on.

Comment: Ummm... which is the external router?:D the Prolink? Thanks for answering!

Comment: The external router is the one that is connected to the internet, in your case the Prolink.